# Organizing github repository for java 6 and 7

Tags: java, github, multiple-versions

I am wanting to create a gihub repository that offers benchmarking code that 
works for concurrent features available only in JDK 1.7 (Fork/Join) as well as for older ones found in JDK 1.6.

Offering both options is important for what I need.

Does anyone have a recommendation how should I structure the repository.

I was planning on having a repo called  and under it:

```
jdk17
   build
   src
     mycode ...
jdk16
   build
   src
     mycode
```

Please suggest any alternatives, possibly use of Maven or other more practical approaches, if any.

Comment: Since Java SE 7 is pretty much backward compatible with Java SE 6, any reason not to include everything together, and simply not compile some files when built with JDK 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to have source code for both versions available at the same time, you can just put them in separate branches.